# Qmail Spam I think someone is injecting mail or gained access to a pop account

Tags: spam, email

I don't know how to detect if qmail has been hijacked

I looked and saw a bunch of

Dec 23 14:10:57  qmail: 1261606257.101924 starting delivery 36: msg 8423008 to remote ysacy2966@prima.net.ar
Dec 23 14:10:57  qmail: 1261606257.630379 starting delivery 22: msg 8421857 to remote ogiqar6234@rima-tde.net

load is at 20 think spammer is sending mail through the server?

What can I do to try and stop it, or read the mail to see where its coming from? If its a php form or pop account.

Comment: What kind of logging is available? SMTP logging? MTA logging? Have you run the equivalant of netstat to look at current network connections?

Answer (score 1):

/var/qmail/bin/qmail-qstat

or better

/var/qmail/bin/qmail-qread

will be the starting point.

Then locate a SPAM message ID and search for a file with that name in /var/qmail/queue (find /var/qmail/queue -iname ).

Find common characteristic to all SPAM (say IP/Subject, From, Auth information etc.) and use [qmHandle](http://qmhandle.sf.net) to remove emails from queue and take steps to make sure that SPAM stop coming.